# Replacing [] with at() at compile time

Tags: c++, gcc, vector

I was wondering if there was a way to replace vector access via
myVec[i]
to
myVec.at(i)
at compile-time, ideally in GCC. The motivation is tracing out-of-bounds accesses - using at() these will throw std::exception.

I know that GCC offers a standard container debug mode https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html#debug_mode.using.mode but you have to recompile everything (I work on a very large project).

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do this?

Comment: I updated it. at() throws an exception on out-of-bounds access, so this would help tracking them down.

Comment: Since this is template code, you can simply take the source-code and apply the same checking of `at()` in the `operator[]` of the relevant templates.

Comment: Good idea. I wonder if that might lead to the same ABI/recompilation issues I was worried about.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think OP is using standard library containers, in which case you cannot define your own `operator[]`.

Comment: It isn't possible without recompilation, since the compiled code is already compiled as calling `operator[]` which is inlined and doesn't do any checks. So the best you can do is just use GCC's debug mode which you already mentioned.

Comment: Well, without recompillation, valgrind is probably your best bet. You will need to do some recompilation to insert more code otherwise.

Comment: @vstoftco: STL lives in header files, which is why I said "take the source file and modify it to do the same thing as at". As far as I understand it, the compiler will compile the headers to determine what each method does - or have I missed something?

Comment: @MatsPetersson ahh ok, I misunderstood your comment *" you can simply take the source-code and apply the same checking of at() in the operator[] of the relevant templates"*, I thought you referred to `operator[]` in a custom class. Modifying the standard library is a bit sketchy though ;)

Comment: The STL is not written for ease of reading, that is true. But it's not a huge change to modify it to check for the limit, I'd have thought (and I have spent some time looking inside various STL functions). Whether it is better than using GCC's debug mode is of course a different question - probably not. And of course, you'd want to keep that copy of the header somewhere it doesn't accidentally get compiled into other things, such as the compiler itself... :)

Comment: Recompiling seems like the easiest way of doing this.  How long will it take to recompile? a day? a week?  In the meantime, you can do something else.